# What are the advantages of running SQL Server in a Docker container?

Tags: sql-server, docker

I need to run an SQL Server (Express) instance on my dev machine to work with a web application.

I recently started working with Docker and I'm wondering if there is some advantage using the [Microsoft SQLServer Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express/) instead of simply installing SQL Server on my machine.

I'm working on a Win10 machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Fast installation**

Better to say no installation needed if you already have Docker installed. Just provide 3 env vars (Server type, password and accept EULA) to `docker run` and you're ready.

**Automatic installation/deploy**

You can start SQL with just few commands, no need for user interactive process. Very useful for CI/CD pipeline.

**Cloud-ready**

Want to run you solution on VPS? Or GCP/AKS/AWS? You are just one step away from `kubernetes` - your containers can be run anywhere.

**Cheap**

Windows-based virtual servers are more expensive than Linux. Testing your solution could be done on Linux runners and save you money.

**Testing against different servers/version**

Following @DanGuzman 's comment, you can test your solution with different version on SQL server with just changing the `tag` of an image or SQL Server type in environment var.

**Isolation**

Easily create separate bridge networks with SQL server, control access. Can start several instances on one PC at once easily with just separating networks by Docker means.

**Resetting**

Testing requires that you can reset all changes and start all tests from scratch (from same starting point). With containers and their volumes you achieve that with one command.

**Transparent configuration**

You provide `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` where all steps are explicitly written clear. No need to provide additional readme's on how to setup your server.

**Cross-platform**

Developers can use different operating systems when working on big project (our case). Docker configuration will run on any without changes. Maybe you designes use MacOS and also want to run solution locally? Easy with Docker.

Comment: Adding that database containers are especially useful for CI/CD pipelines where one can build, deploy, unit test, and tear down quickly and repeatedly.

Comment: Another advantage of containers is one can build many custom images for different SQL versions and/or configurations (e.g. different collations for SQL Server on Windows) without many local named instances or VMs.

Comment: Good answer, thanks. What about the backup of the database when it’s in a container?

Comment: Data may reside in a volume, even in a bind-mounts. The idea is more about keeping the engine itself containerized.